# How to align table footnotes with kableExtra?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

I tried to use `kableExtra::add_footnote()` to create footnotes for my PDF output. I want to make the footnotes align in both sides, reduce the font size and the line space. I did try to add `threeparttable = T` in my code, but it didn't work.

```
library(magrittr)
data("mtcars")
tbl <- tibble::tibble(mpg = mean(mtcars$mpg), cyl = mean(mtcars$cyl), disp = mean(mtcars$disp)) %>% as.data.frame()

rownames(tbl) <- c("Mean")
knitr::kable(tbl, "latex",
             booktabs = T,
             digits = 2, 
             escape = FALSE) %>% 
  kableExtra::add_header_above(c("Mean" = 4)) %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position", full_width = T,  font_size = 10) %>% 
  kableExtra::column_spec(1, width = "3cm") %>% 
  kableExtra::add_footnote("I want to add some long long long long long footnotes here, and I want the format looks elegant enough.")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF0qJ.png)

Comment: Could you please provide your YAML header?

Comment: header-includes:
- \usepackage{caption}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}

Comment: I guess you need also to add `\usepackage{threeparttable}`

Comment: It still doesn't work. If I add `threeparttable = T` in `add_footnote()`. There is only `\begin{threeparttable}` in my PDF output. I don't know why it can't be rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `full_width = T` in `kable_styling` is the option that causes the issue. Without that it seems to work for me.

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{caption} 
  - \usepackage{booktabs} 
  - \usepackage{longtable}
  - \usepackage{threeparttablex} 
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(magrittr)
data("mtcars")
tbl <- data.frame(mpg = mean(mtcars$mpg), cyl = mean(mtcars$cyl), disp = mean(mtcars$disp))

rownames(tbl) <- c("Mean")
knitr::kable(tbl, "latex",
             booktabs = T,
             digits = 2, 
             escape = FALSE) %>% 
  kableExtra::add_header_above(c("Mean" = 4)) %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position", font_size = 10) %>% 
  kableExtra::column_spec(c(1:4), width = "3cm") %>%
  kableExtra::add_footnote(
    "I want to add some long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long footnotes here.",
    threeparttable = T
  )
```
````

[image: rendered result]